How to test that my app invokes proper handler for various HTTP requests
I have an app that invokes different handlers for different URL paths. Say, something like that:
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.Handle("/someURLpath", someHandler)
mux.Handle("/someOtherURLpath", someOtherHandler)
...
// and so on

I want to make sure that proper handler is invoked for every URL path.
I went through several test case examples, all of these examples actually imply that test request triggers correct handler.
For example, standard httptest.Server is created with certain handler functions:
ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello, client")
    }))

This already implies that httptest.Server.Client() will invoke this very handler, not any other.
What I want is to feed my web app with several HTTP requests with different URL paths (/someURLpath, /someOtherURLpath, ...), and test that someHandler() is invoked for /someURLpath, someOtherHandler() is invoked for /someOtherURLpath, and so on.
How can I do this?

Make an HTTP request to the actual mux.

net/http/server.go has func (mux *ServeMux) findHandler(r *Request) (h Handler, patStr string, _ *pattern, matches []string), however it is unexported and uses some other unexported package functions.
There is also func (mux *ServeMux) ServeHTTP(w ResponseWriter, r *Request), but it chooses handler under the hood. Which means I can see what's inside the response, not which handler had been invoked

Register your handlers with a wrapper that sets a flag.

Go has a package in its standard library called httptest. You can make a request using this library then verify the response (http status, headers, content, etc). example https://speedscale.com/blog/testing-golang-with-httptest/ docs https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest

I want to make sure that proper handler is invoked for every URL path So basically, you want to unit test http.ServeMux?

Markus W Mahlberg In a sense, yes. I need to migrate an API to Go 1.22 routing, and this API has a kind of clumsy mix of URL path and query parameters, and quite some handlers to do this, that, and other things. I've been looking for some migration tool or framework, but haven't found any
